# Magento 1: Can't override Enterprise/GiftCardAccount/controllers/Adminhtml/GiftcardaccountController.php

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, admin-controller

I can't override the controller inside of the Enterprise/GiftCardAccount/controllers/Adminhtml/ folder

```
<config>
...

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_Module before="Enterprise_GiftCardAccount">Vendor_Module_Adminhtml</Vendor_Module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
...
</config>
```

Note: I also tried with *before="Mage_Adminhtml"* value and nothing

Then I created the controller in my module folder

```
app/code/local/Vendor/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/GiftcardaccountController.php
```

The code in the controller

```
<?php

require_once 'Enterprise/GiftCardAccount/controllers/Adminhtml/GiftcardaccountController.php';
//require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Enterprise_GiftCardAccount').DS.'Adminhtml'.DS.'GiftcardaccountController.php';

class Vendor_Module_Adminhtml_GiftcardaccountController extends Enterprise_GiftCardAccount_Adminhtml_GiftcardaccountController
{}
```

Comment: Does it show any error or what?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya No errors or logs. But, I can fixed the issue and I just posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct config.xml

```
<config>
...

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_Module before="Enterprise_GiftCardAccount_Adminhtml">Vendor_Module_Adminhtml</Vendor_Module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
...
</config>
```

Note: the *"_Adminhtml"* at the end in the before value

```
app/code/local/Vendor/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/GiftcardaccountController.php
```

Then in the controller use this code

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Enterprise_GiftCardAccount').DS.'Adminhtml'.DS.'GiftcardaccountController.php';

class Vendor_Module_Adminhtml_GiftcardaccountController extends Enterprise_GiftCardAccount_Adminhtml_GiftcardaccountController
{
...
```